# Numpad 5 With Numlock won't output 5 unless it is also pressed with the windows key on Windows 10, Same behavior with Virtual Keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, numpad

I'm having the most frustrating problem with Windows 10 after the latest patches were installed on my system. (7/7/2021)

Windows 10 Pro
Version 21H1
OS Build 19043.1151

Keyboard - Logitech G413

The numpad key 5 doesn't work unless it is also pressed in conjunction with the windows key.  This same behavior is exhibited with the virtual keyboard.  I've also tried multiple different keyboards as I have a few extra laying around.  So it appears to be some kind of software issue and not hardware related.  All google searching leads to checking and changing common behavior toggles in the keyboard settings, but these are all turned off on my machine.  Things like control your mouse with a keypad.  Numlock is toggled, all other numpad keys work normally and as expected.  The only key that won't register is the 5 key directly in the middle of the keypad.  As I said, the virtual keyboard does the same thing.  If you click on numpad 5 on the virtual keyboard with the mouse cursor, you can see the button on the virtual keyboard change as if it has been pressed but a 5 is not output unless the windows key is also pressed.

I've tried re-installing keyboard drivers.  I've turned off and on just about every setting there is related to the keyboard, including sticky keys.  I've plugged the keyboards in to every possible USB port on the machine as well.

Comment: Try clean booting as its most likely a program.

Comment: You're right, clean booting seems to work.  This is going to be painful, I've disabled most non-Microsoft services to no avail.  I guess one of their services is causing this issue?  What a nightmare

Comment: It is most likely to be a program rather than a service.

Comment: Try using Autoruns from MS. Make sure to right click it and choose Run As Administrator. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I found the issue, it was related to an Nvidia service.  There are key bindings in their GeForce Experience, a turn on/off microphone function was bound to keypad 5.  Exiting GeForce in the bottom right did nothing because this was actively running as a service.  Once I discovered this I went in, found the keybinds and changed it, which aside from disabling the service fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

GeForce Experience was the culprit.  The In-Game overlay has key bindings setup to toggle different functions for gameplay recordings; such as, mute/unmute microphone, and start/stop recording.  This overlay, if turned on, runs as a service.  So, even if you close GeForce Experience or even exit by right clicking the icon in the taskbar and choosing exit, this service still runs.

If you happen to have any of those functions linked to a single key and not a combination (alt+whatever, fn+whatever, etc.) that key will then become unusable during normal use outside of playing a game, as this service is always running if In-Game Overlay is turned on.  In my case, Numpad 5 was tied to one of these functions and because of that I was unable to actually press Numpad 5 and have it write a 5, even with the use of the virtual keyboard.  All Numpad 5 presses were intercepted by Nvidia's service and used to toggle the micrphone on/off instead of writing a 5.

If you wish to continue using GeForce Experience you should change all key bindings to a combination of alt+[your key here], or some other combination.  Be careful not to choose combinations that already exist, such as ctrl+c, as these will probably be overridden as well.  Either that, or you can turn the In-Game overlay option on before launching a game, and then off once you are out of a game. But this would be tedious and annoying so I would recommend the key combinations.